# Replacing several strings in a list in a single statement

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, replace

I am trying to replace the third and forth words of this list by two different words in one single statement and just can't seem to find of doing it what I tried doesn't work with the error `AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'replace'`:

```
friends = ["Lola", "Loic", "Rene", "Will", "Seb"]
friends.replace("Rene", "Jack").replace("Will", "Morris")
```

Answer (score 8):

If you want to do multiple replacements probably the easiest way is to make a dictionary of what you want to replace with what:

```
replacements = {"Rene": "Jack", "Will": "Morris"}
```

and then use a list comprehension:

```
friends = [replacements[friend] if friend in replacements else friend for friend in friends]
```

Or more compactly, using `dict.get()` with a default value.

```
friends = [replacements.get(friend, friend) for friend in friends]
```

Comment: Even simpler: `[replacements.get(f, f) for f in friends]`

Comment: good point @pault - I thought of using `.get` but for some reason didn't think of providing the original as the default :-)

Comment: Thank you for your answer my problem with this is that then its not in a single statement :/

Comment: I thought of using the dictionnary but then end up using two statements

Comment: Why do you have to do it in a single statement? (You could make this into a single statement by not defining `replacemens` as a variable and using it as a literal value in the comprehension - but that would be a long line, hard to read and therefore not recommended.)

Comment: Thank you for this explanation. I know it doesn't make much sense, but it's the requirement (from the professor) I guess to learn how to code in a shorter way and therefore not have useless lines. But if you say that the single statement, in this case, is not readable, then i don't understant why

Answer (score 1):

Another way, if you don't mind the overhead of converting the list to a `pandas.Series`:

```
import pandas as pd

friends = ["Lola", "Loic", "Rene", "Will", "Seb"]

friends = pd.Series(friends).replace(to_replace={"Rene":"Jack", "Will":"Morris"}).tolist()
print(friends)
#['Lola', 'Loic', 'Jack', 'Morris', 'Seb']
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a not so pretty solution, but a one-liner nevertheless:

```
friends = list(map(lambda x: x if x != "Will" else "Morris", map(lambda x: x if x != "Rene" else "Jack", friends)))
```

**Brief explanation:**

It's a "map(lambda, list)" solution, whose output list is passed as input list to another outer "map(lambda, list)" solution.

The `lambda` in the inner `map` is for replacing `"Will"` with `"Morris"`.

The `lambda` in the outer `map` is for replacing `"Rene"` with `"Jack"`

Comment: Thank you for this explanation